# Restivus does not set up endpoint Meteor 1.4

Tags: javascript, curl, meteor, postman, restivus

I have trouble creating an API Endpoint in a Meteor 1.4.1 app using Restivus.

Here is my current code :

```
import { Restivus } from 'meteor/nimble:restivus'
import { Stripe } from '../stripe/stripe'

export const loadApi = function(){
    console.log('loading api')
    var Api = new Restivus({
        enableCors: true, 
        prettyJson:true
    })

    Api.addRoute('/charge', {
        post: {
            action: function(){
                console.log('* Charging customer')
                console.log(this)
                console.log(this.bodyparams)
                Stripe.chargeCustomer('foobar',9900)
                return {
                    statusCode:204,
                    body:'foobar'
                }
            }
        }
    })
console.log(Api)
}
```

Then I load this code on the `server/main.js` `Meteor.startup` function.
The API seems to be correctly defined, as the `console.log` prints the Restivus object with the correct `_routes` attribute.

However,sending a post request to `http://localhost:3000/api/charge` does not trigger the function (the `console.log` are not executed).

Any idea about what could be wrong with my code ? I use Meteor 1.4.1, so it might be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the leading slash from your route, so 'charge' instead of '/charge'.

[Relevant issue on GitHub.](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/pull/174)

Comment: @EricBurel I'm doing exactly the same way but still not able to get the response of GET and POST of my api's.
I also using FlowRouter for dashboard route and it will not impact API routing correct ?
The same way i did in meteor 1.0 and it was working fine at that time. so is it because of meteor 1.4 ?
Any idea ?

Comment: @Shrinath could you show us the code ? FlowRouter should have nothing to do with this indeed (except maybe if you use its SSR branch ?)

Answer (score 0):

I have not use restivus, but in your code, should it be `Api.addRoute('/api/charge'` instead of `Api.addRoute('/charge'` ?

Comment: Hi, no Restivus adds the `/api/` prefix itself according to doc. Anyway I still tried to request `/charge` but it did not work either.

Comment: What about trying to request `/api/charge` instead of just `/charge`?

Comment: Yes `/api/charge` is the correct endpoint, but I had to set it up as `charge` instead of `/charge` in my code (the Restivus doc examples are misleading), the accepted answer gives a link to the corresponding Github issue.